# How to cover whole PC screen with software

Tags: c#, winforms, fullscreen

Link you have provided as answer is not answer for my question. With kiok mode you can add only window store app nd winform app. So question is that how i can use kiosk mode for win app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlaZ4.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWS3g.jpg)
I have developed Point of sale application in c# and i have following  two requirements:

1. I want when user start up computer then POS will start up automatic

   Solutions Tried : I Know there is a startup folder where we can copy shortcut        of software and on computer start up this application will start up automatic.  Is there any better practice to that.
2. User not able to see taskbar or POS will cover whole screen. Requirement is user can use computer for another purpose.

I have no idea how to implement 2.

Comment: Read about kiosk mode in Windows. For [Windows 10](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-device-for-anyone-to-use).

Comment: @Dawnkeeper fullscreen does not effectively prevent the use of the task bar. You can minimize the app or press key combinations or swipe the touch screen to show the task bar or charms bar.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions). It shows you how to setup Kiosk Mode in Windows.

Kiosk mode in Windows allow you to setup Windows to run only one program that user can use. This mode is for Universal App and for Classical Applications but is has some limitation by Windows edition.

Comment: Hi DanilT thanks for answer ,in Kiosk mode when i copy application in startup folder and application startup it runs in background and i need to click on Task view to grap applicaiton on front and second when i click on login then second form that open i open again in background and i need to click task view to bring form in front, Thanks if u can help me in that

Comment: @Seeker It's very hard to understand what you want. Do I understand you correctly, you want to application to be started automatically in Kiosk mode ?

Comment: I have uploaded screen shots . When i run application then i run in background and i need to click on red circled "Task viewer " to fetch them on front .